# doInBackground() in AsyncTask not able to make connection

Tags: java, android, url, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to make a registration activity for my android application. I'm using AsyncTask to perform this. But the code doesn't seem to connect to the Database at my server (not localhost) as it doesn't show any connection being made to the server in the Android debugger and monitor. Help?

```
private void registrationProcess(String name, String email, String mob, String password)
```

{

```
String urlSuffix = "?userName=" + name + "&userMobile=" + mob + "&userEmail=" + email + "&userPassword=" + password;
class RegistrationProcess extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog loadingRegister;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loadingRegister = ProgressDialog.show(RegisterActivity.this, "Registering...", "Please wait...", true, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String s = params[0];
        BufferedReader bufferedreader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(REGISTER_URL + s);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.connect();
                bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String result = bufferedreader.readLine();
                con.disconnect();
                return  result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
    }
}
RegistrationProcess rgp = new RegistrationProcess();
rgp.execute(urlSuffix);
```

}

Comment: you should show at least the way you are doing that, otherwise, cannot help with your problem

Comment: Sure, I was just adding that..

Comment: try to add in your catch this: System.out.println(ex.getMessage()) or something to see the exception, because you are not handling your exception, just are returning null...

Comment: No exception takes places. It just doesn't connects to the server.

Comment: get the response code. Plus just put the printstacktrace in catch to get a proper idea. Remove it later.

Comment: Check if you adding INTERNET permission in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

```
        Try this code 

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // entrer URL ou le fichier php réside
        String s = params[0];
        try {
            url = new URL(REGISTER_URL+s);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }
        try{
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNEXTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // apprend parameters to URL
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("somthing",params[0 or 1 or ...]);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            // ouvrir une connexion pour envoyer des informations
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception";
        }

        try{

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();
            if(response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                //Lire data envoyer depuis le serveur
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
                InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                    result.append(line);
                }
                //envoyer data to "" onPostExecute "" methode
                return(result.toString());
            }
            else{
                return("Echec...");
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception";
        }
        finally{
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    } //
```